# How to add non duplicate objects in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to add non-duplicate objects into a new array.

```
var array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'one'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    label: 'one'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: 'two'
  }
];

var uniqueProducts = array.filter(function(elem, i, array) {
    return array.indexOf(elem) === i;
});

console.log('uniqueProducts', uniqueProducts);
// output: [object, object, object]
```

[live code](https://jsfiddle.net/ptongalex/a17z2tyb/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you use an object to keep track of your unique keys. Then, you convert the object to an array of all property values.

It's best to include a unique `id`-like property that you can use as an identifier. If you don't have one, you need to generate it yourself using `JSON.stringify` or a custom method. Stringifying your object will have a downside: the order of the keys does not have to be consistent.

You *could* create an `objectsAreEqual` method with support for deep comparison, but this *will* slow your function down immensely.

In two steps:

```js
var array=[{id:1,label:"one"},{id:1,label:"one"},{id:2,label:"two"}];

// Create a string representation of your object
function getHash(obj) {
   return Object.keys(obj)
     .sort() // Keys don't have to be sorted, do it manually here
     .map(function(k) {
       return k + "_" + obj[k]; // Prefix key name so {a: 1} != {b: 1}
     })
     .join("_"); // separate key-value-pairs by a _
}


function getHashBetterSolution(obj) {
  return obj.id; // Include unique ID in object and use that
};

// When using `getHashBetterSolution`:
// { '1': { id: '1', label: 'one' }, '2': /*etc.*/ }
var uniquesObj = array.reduce(function(res, cur) {
  res[getHash(cur)] = cur;
  return res;
}, {});

// Convert back to array by looping over all keys                             
var uniquesArr =  Object.keys(uniquesObj).map(function(k) {
  return uniquesObj[k];
});

console.log(uniquesArr);

// To show the hashes
console.log(uniquesObj);
```

Comment: what happens if I don't know my keys ? (I don't have 'id')

Comment: You'll have to create a function that makes a `string` hash from any object. If they're not nested and only contain primitives, it's most likely a concatenation of all properties. I'll include an example.

Answer (score 4):

I like the class based approach using es6. The example uses lodash's _.isEqual method to determine equality of objects.

```js
var array = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'one'
}, {
  id: 1,
  label: 'one'
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'two'
}];

class UniqueArray extends Array {
  constructor(array) {
    super();
    array.forEach(a => {
      if (! this.find(v => _.isEqual(v, a))) this.push(a);
    });
  }
}

var unique = new UniqueArray(array);
console.log(unique);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a hash table and store the found `id`.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, label: 'one' }, { id: 1, label: 'one' }, { id: 2, label: 'two' }],
    uniqueProducts = array.filter(function(elem) {
        return !this[elem.id] && (this[elem.id] = true);
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log('uniqueProducts', uniqueProducts);
```

Check with all properties

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, label: 'one' }, { id: 1, label: 'one' }, { id: 2, label: 'two' }],
    keys = Object.keys(array[0]),                 // get the keys first in a fixed order
    uniqueProducts = array.filter(function(a) {
        var key = keys.map(function (k) { return a[k]; }).join('|');
        return !this[key] && (this[key] = true);
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log('uniqueProducts', uniqueProducts);
```

Comment: what happens if I don't know my keys ? (I don't have 'id')

Comment: Because you store `keys` only once, `{ id: 1, label: 'one' }, { id: 1, label: 'one', test: 2 }` will be considered duplicates

Comment: @user3297291, `keys` contains only `['id', 'label']`. `key` (without *s*) contains different values.

Comment: What I meant is that you use the `keys` in the first object to base your hash on. If a later object is a superset of the first one (i.e. same `label` and `id`, but with additional properties), it will not be considered a unique object by your filter. But I might be wrong.

Comment: that is right, but it is not likely to have different property count in arrays with the same (comparable) structure.

Comment: Agreed, wouldn't make much sense. But the comment "I don't know my keys" kind of contradicts that for this specific case ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `map()` to create key for each object and filter to remove duplicates.

```js
var array = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'one'
}, {
  id: 1,
  label: 'one'
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'two'
}];

var result = array.filter(function(e) {
  var key = Object.keys(e).map(k => e[k]).join('|');
  if (!this[key]) {
    this[key] = true;
    return true;
  }
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: what happens if I don't know my keys ? (I don't have 'id')

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to extract out the unique array and the unique ids like this:

```js
var array=[{id:1,label:"one"},{id:1,label:"one"},{id:2,label:"two"}];

var result = array.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  if(prev.ids.indexOf(curr.id) === -1) {
    prev.array.push(curr);
    prev.ids.push(curr.id);
  }
  return prev;
}, {array: [], ids: []});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

If you don't know the keys, you can do this - create a unique key that would help you identify duplicates - so I did this:

1. `concat` the list of `key`s and `value`s of the objects
2. Now `sort` them for the unique key like `1|id|label|one`

This handles situations when the object properties are not in order:

```js
var array=[{id:1,label:"one"},{id:1,label:"one"},{id:2,label:"two"}];

var result = array.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  var tracker = Object.keys(curr).concat(Object.keys(curr).map(key => curr[key])).sort().join('|');
  if(!prev.tracker[tracker]) {
    prev.array.push(curr);
    prev.tracker[tracker] = true;
  }
  return prev;
}, {array: [], tracker: {}});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```